# Confused with doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen

I want to use doxygen to generate a file group. like this：
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyzpb.png][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyzpb.png)

All header files are in the include group, and all source files are in the src group. 
What should I do？Now all the files are mixed together， like this:
[image]

Comment: thanks @kiran Biradar, I don't know how to display pictures directly.

Comment: You speak of 'include group' and 'src group' or did you mean 'include folder' / 'include directory' etc? Which version of doxygen did you use? Which configuration settings did you make different from the default  settings?

Comment: doxygen 1.8.11, only set SOURCE_BROWSER = YES. I just want the header files to appear separate from the source files, which makes them look clearer.

Comment: Are they in the same directory or in separate directories? (Note 1.8.11 is quite old December 2015, the current version is is 1.8.16)

Comment: They are in separete directories. I installed it using the apt command, it seems that I need to manually install a latest version.

Comment: I have the files `aa.h` and `bb.h` in the `include` directory and `aa.c` and `bb.c` in the `src` directory and I see with the 1.8.11 version and with the current version the "non-mixed" version. My `Doxyfile`  only contains the lines: `RECURSIVE=YES` and as you use it `SOURCE_BROWSER=YES`. As you say you only changed `SOURCE_BROWSER` how can it see the files in the sub-directories, so I think either you see nothing from the sub-directories or you have some other settings set as well.

Comment: I mean the first picture, they are in separate directories. In my experimental program, all files are in the same directory, i don't know how to set it up to achieve this effect.I will install the latest version first and check if they are still mixed. Thanks very much, you always appear in time.

Comment: In the newest version they will be mixed as well, I don't know of a way doxygen could know how to place the files in a tree structure unless the tree structure is present.

Comment: It seems to be, maybe only through the original tree structure to achieve this effect.